# Parsing xml document using PHP <![CDATA[...]]>

Tags: php, xml, dom

I know this question is asked many times before but still can't find the desired result I have been looking for parsing xml document using php DOMDocument function.

Initially my xml document named 'local.xml' contains the following script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <host><![CDATA[name123]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root45]]></username> 
    </global>
</config>
```

I want to change "`<host><![CDATA[name123]]></host>`" to "`<host><![CDATA[name456]]></host>`"

I have php code that can change the value inside  tag. Here is the php code

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('local.xml');
$config = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "global" );
foreach( $config as $global )
{

    $hosts=$global->getElementsByTagName( "host" );
    $usernames=$global->getElementsByTagName( "username" );
    $a = "<![CDATA[name456]]>";
    $hosts1=$hosts->item(0)->nodeValue=$a;
}
$doc->save('local.xml');
?>
```

When i execute the above code, the output in the xml file is coming as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <host>&lt;![CDATA[name456]]&gt;</host>
        <username><![CDATA[root45]]></username> 
    </global>
</config>
```

How can I convert `"&lt;" to "<"` and `"&gt;" to ">"` in xml document?

I have tried `$a = htmlspecialchars("<![CDATA[name456]]>");` as well as `$a = html_entity_decode("<![CDATA[name456]]>");` still it is giving the same output as seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally After some more hours and hours of trails and errors, I managed to solve it. Had Daniel Sloof not shown the tip, my code would have been useless. Thanks Daniel Sloof

here is the final code

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('local.xml');
$config = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "global" );
foreach( $config as $global )
{
    $hosts=$global->getElementsByTagName( "host" );
    $oldcdata=$hosts->item(0)->nodeValue="";
    $newcdata=$doc->createCDATASection("name456");
    $hosts1=$hosts->item(0)->appendChild($newcdata);
}
$doc->save('local.xml');
?>
```

By adding null value to `$oldcdata` it will empty the value inside `<host><![CDATA[name123]]></host>` tag this will become `<host></host>` in xml file

Now we add a new value to `$newcdata` it will then be appended to `<host></host>` by using appendChild($newcdata) and it will become `<host><![CDATA[name456]]></host>`

Answer (score 3):

Use [DOMDocument::createCDATASection](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php).

Comment: Thanks, after going through hours and hours of coding and many trails and errors with DOMDocuemtn::createCDATASection, im still stuck in this. I would be gratefull if you would provide me with code to implement this correctly